# Mutator Methods that don't allow certain values

Tags: mutators

How would I write a mutator method for an instance variable of type int with the identifier employeeID. The mutator method cannot allow values larger than 9999 or less than 0 and automatically adjust values outside of that range to the appropriate max or minimum values. I can't figure out how to get the mutator method to not allow certain values and return values outside of the range to the min or max values.

I am using java

Comment: You need to post the code that you already tried, along with what exactly isn't working as intended. SO is not a place to have others write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea of a cap is pick the minimum of the number and the maximum amount allowed. Then pick the maximum of the result and the smallest amount allowed:

```
Math.max(Math.min(num, max), min)
```

```js
function cap(num, max, min) {
    return Math.max(Math.min(num, max), min);
}
function calcCap() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value
    ,   max = document.getElementById('max').value
    ,   min = document.getElementById('min').value
    ;
    var result = cap(input, max, min);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
Number to cap: <input id= 'input' type='number' value='7' onchange='calcCap();' onkeyup='calcCap();'/><br/>
Max: <input id= 'max' type='number' value='5' onchange='calcCap(); onkeyup='calcCap();''/><br/>
Min: <input id= 'min' type='number' value='2' onchange='calcCap();' onkeyup='calcCap();'/><br/>
Result:<div id='result'></div>
```